# Python multiprocessing pool imap_unordered

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool, unordered

I'm using Python multiprocessing pool imap_unordered.

In a generator, I'm filling my inputlist in **fillInputList**, sending this inputList to **prepare_data_fill_arrays**

**prepare_data_fill_arrays** takes a long time, it reads a file and fills the arrays.

When arrays are filled, I'm accumulating them in **accumulated array**

Both **fillInputList** and **prepare_data_fill_arrays**  have print lines to show that they have entered to the functions.

However, none of them is written, but only:

- Worker PID XXXX in accumulate
- Worker PID XXXX in accumulate

These are written.

What can be the reason, it does not wait for **prepare_data_fill_arrays** to finish.

```py
numofSimulations=10
chromNamesList=['chr1', 'chr2', 'chr3', 'chr4', 'chr5', 'chr6', 'chr7', 'chrX', 'chr8', 'chr9', 'chr10', 'chr11', 'chr12', 'chr13', 'chr14', 'chr15', 'chr16', 'chr17', 'chr18', 'chr20', 'chrY', 'chr19', 'chr22', 'chr21', 'chrM']
sim_nums = range(0, numofSimulations+1)
sim_num_chr_tuples=((sim_num,chrLong) for sim_num in sim_nums for chrLong in chromNamesList)

for arrayList in pool.imap_unordered(prepare_data_fill_arrays, (fillInputList(simNum,chrLong,x,y,z,a,b,c) for simNum,chrLong in sim_num_chr_tuples),chunksize=1):

    print('Worker pid %s in accumulate' %str(os.getpid()))
    array1 = arrayList[0]
    array2 = arrayList[1]
    accumulateArray(accumulatedArray1, array1)
    accumulateArray(accumulatedArray2, array2)
```

Comment: It's a process pool. It just starts the processes and returns. You should wait for all of them to complete what they're doing and then enter the for loop.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html  How to wait for all  of them to complete? In the python  documentation for imap_unordered usage, it is called in for loop and there is no extra check mechanism. So what I understand is whenever a result is returned it enters the for loop.